# Drag file from OSX Finder to JTable fails in Java 11

Tags: macos, drag-and-drop, java-11, finder

We've recently upgrade our Application to run under Java 11 (used to be Java 8).
There is one panel on our apps main screen that Files can be dropped onto.
This works fine on Windows but not on OSX. (used to work under Java 8, failed after switching to Java 11).

A file can be dragged from another Java application that supports it, but NOT from Finder.
The TransferHandler.canImport() method is never called.

The DropTarget.dragOver() method IS called, but the drop() method is never called.  I can't trace into runtime library methods, as it doesn't have line number information.

I've found that I CAN drag files from Finder to another Java app, or to a JDialog in our main app.
It only fails if the JTable is in a panel in our main application window.  So our app must be doing something odd to cause it to fail.

The problem is finding out WHY it fails, only on OSX.  This is a LARGE application, and the main window is quite complex.  Posting a Self Contained source example is impossible - especially since the simple case works.

What I could REALLY use is a Java 11 Runtime library that has line number information so I can step into it.  Yes, I have the full source that came with the Java 11 JDK. (Adopt OpenJDK)  I've been unable to get it to compile under Eclipse.

Any suggestions on what our app could be doing to cause this to fail?  Or where I can find a Debug Java 11 runtime library?

Answer (score 0):

Sure would have been nice to have a Debug runtime library.

The issue is that on the calls to DropTarget.dragEnter() and .dragOver(), the data in the Transferable and the getCurrentDataFlavors() is invalid on OSX.
getCurrentDataFlavors() will return a list of ALL data flavors - none of which will have any transferData. (this means that the data is also invalid in all the calls to TransferHandler.canImport() as well.)

The ONLY time the data is valid is in the TransferHandler.importData() call.

Our code was checking to see that the user was dragging a file of the correct type in the canImport() call.  Since all the data is now invalid (OSX, Java 11) that call was throwing an NPE (since the getCurrentDataFlavors() included our desired flavor, but the getTransferData(flavor) return null.  Note that this worked correctly with Java 8.

Combine that with the Runtime drag handling code that silently ignores exceptions, well, not quite ignores them, it disables all further Drop operations on that target when one happens.  That makes it really difficult to track down what is happening.